# Hough Transform Equation

Tags: image-processing

I was wondering why the Hough Transform uses `rho=xcos(theta) + ysin(theta)` for representation of a straight line `(y=mx+b)`. I tried to work through this (and went to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) about this), but can not find a way to derive one from the other.

Does anyone know how to derive one from the other?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Derivation:

The equation `x/a + y/b = 1`:

- defines a line
- has x-intercept = a
- has y-intercept = b

From trigonometry, recall how a ray rotated by angle `t` will project onto the x- and y- axes according to `(angle=t, radius=1) -> (x=cos(t), y=sin(t))`*

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle.svg]

Draw the tangent line at the labelled point. Trigonometry (or even geometry with similar triangles) tells us that the tangent line intersects at `x=1/cos(t)`, `y=1/sin(t)`. Thus the line a distance 1 away will have `a=1/cos(t)` and `b=1/sin(t)`, and thus described by `x/(1/cos(t)) + y/(1/sin(t)) = 1`...

... which is just `cos(t) x + sin(t) y = rho` where `rho=1`

You can see that `rho` corresponds to how far the line is from the origin (either by playing around with the equation, or by noting that multiplication here just scales all values by the same amount, effectively rescaling the grid).

---

*see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle.svg for credit

Answer (score 7):

That's just a transform from a linear coordinate system to a rotational one. The reason for this is outlined in the Wikipedia article:

> In the Hough transform, a main idea is to consider the characteristics of the straight line not as image points (x1, y1), (x2, y2), etc., but instead, in terms of its parameters, i.e., the slope parameter m and the intercept parameter b. Based on that fact, the straight line y = mx + b can be represented as a point (b, m) in the parameter space. However, one faces the problem that **vertical lines give rise to unbounded values of the parameters m and b**. For computational reasons, it is therefore better to use a different pair of parameters, denoted r and θ (theta), for the lines in the Hough transform.

And to transform between the two, use the equation `y = -(cos(theta)/sin(theta))x + r/sin(theta)`. Thus `m = -(cos(theta)/sin(theta))` and `b = r/sin(theta)`. These obviously break down when `sin(theta)=0` or `theta=0`, which is why the rotational coordinate system is preferred (there aren't any problems with lines with infinite slopes).

Comment: I got the rest, but I dont see how m = -(cos(theta)/sin(theta)) and b = r/sin(theta)... (quite embarrassed to say), everything else made sense

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sin(theta)/cos(theta)`, since slope is rise over run?

Comment: @JonathanM: It would be if you were measuring the slope of the line from the origin to the `y=mx+b` line. However, you're not, and the slope of the `y=mx+b` line is equal to the negative reciprocal of the tangent line from that line to the origin. If you look at ninjagecko's answer you can see that this means that `m = -(cos(theta)/sin(theta))`.

Answer (score 4):

Polar coordinate system is 2-D coordinate system that has a reference point (like origin) called pole and a line from the pole called the polar axis. Each point in the Polar coordinate system is represented as (rho, theta) where 'rho' is the distance between the pole (origin) and the point and 'theta' is the angle between the polar axis and the line joining the pole and the point. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#/media/File:Examples_of_Polar_Coordinates.svg).

The Polar coordinate (rho, theta) can be converted to Cartesian coordinate (x,y) using the following trigonometric equations.

```
x = rho cos theta       ----(1) 
y = rho sin theta       ----(2)
```

Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) for more info.

How do we get the above equations?

The equations use concepts of a right angle (trignonometry)

See the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#/media/File:Polar_to_cartesian.svg).

```
cos theta = adjacent-side/hypotenuse = x/rho,  thus we get (1)     
sin theta = opposite-side/hypotenuse = y/rho,  thus we get (2)
and Pythagorean theorem says,
hypotenuse^2 = adjacent side ^2 + opposite side^2, so
rho^2 = x^2 + y^2       ----(3)
```

Now let's derive the relationship between Cartesian coordinate (x,y) and Polar coordinate (rho,theta)

```
rho^2 = x^2 + y^2       ---- from (3)
rho^2 = x*x  +  y*y
rho^2 = x(rho cos theta) + y (rho sin theta)   ---- from (1) and (2)  
rho^2 = rho(x cos theta + y sin theta)
rho = x cos theta + y sin theta
```

Comment: even thought the code may solve the issue, please provide some additional explanation to it.

Comment: To the folks in review: this is not code, it is the derivation of an equation as asked in the question. To the author of the answer: if you preface your answer with a bit of text you will avoid people misinterpreting your answer, and potentially make the answer even more useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Text added.

Answer (score -1):

Each pair of `rho, theta` relates to an `x,y` pair for a given line in that the distance `rho` from the origin at angle `theta` places you at an `x,y` coordinate on the line.

The `rho, theta` equation is used instead of `y=mx+b` so that a sequence of `rho, theta` values can be put into the equation without computational problems that arise with the `y=mx+b` method where the slope is undefined (that is, the line is vertical).

Comment: Each (rho, theta) pair relates to a series of (x, y) pairs, since it describes a line. Just like the (m, b) pair describes a series of (x, y) pairs. It is not a single (x, y) pair.

Comment: I honestly don't remember answering this question. :)